# How to configure visual regression testing using Loki for Angular and Web components in Storybook

Tags: automated-tests, storybook, lokijs, snapshot-testing, visual-testing

We have a design system with the core components built on Stencil and cross-compiled across React and Angular frameworks. Ideally we have all the components in **React, Angular and Web-components**. We use storybook as Component explorer. Now that we have a need for visual regression testing, I have been going through many visual regression test tools that there and found **Loki** to be most suitable.

I was able to successfully configure **Loki for React** components alone by passing the command line arguments

```
yarn loki test -- --port 6003
```

where my react components in storybook run on port 6003. Angular and web components in storybook run on ports 6004 and 6002 respectively.

The [documentation for Loki](https://loki.js.org/getting-started.html), has configurations for react and native react only. Not sure if I have missed for the rest.

But I am clueless about how this has to be done for Angular and Web-components. Any leads on this is much appreciated!